# Hover text change opacity on div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have a list panel with different words each word explains a div to the right.
I'm trying to change the opacity of the matching div to 1.0 when hovering the matching word.

```
<html> #HTML SETUP 
 <div class="Settings">
   <ul>
    <li class="SettingsSlideshow">
     <h3>Slideshow</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="SlideshowImage">
     <h4>Image</h4>
    </li>
    <li class="SlideshowTitle">
     <h4>Title</h4>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="Slideshow">
 </div>
</html> 

<script type="text/javascript"> #JAVASCRIPT
$(function(){
 $(".SettingsSlideshow").hover(function(){
  $(".Slideshow").css({opacity: 1.0});
 });
});
</script>
```

This is just one example of what I'm trying to achieve. This don't work, Do I need to define x:hover in css as well? I have defined a opacity: 0.7 on each div in css. Mabye I need to define it: (".Settings ul li SettingSlideshow")?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Seems to work properly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Da76P/
Make sure to put something inside the div you are changing opacity for.

Comment: Maybe it's something with my div setup then, It works now when I added  },function(){
$(".Slideshow").css({opacity: 0.0});// here set your rest opacity between 0 to 1

Comment: Thanks everyone for fast answers, rly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $(".SettingsSlideshow").hover(function(){
  $(".Slideshow").css({opacity: 1.0});
 },function(){
$(".Slideshow").css({opacity: 0.0});// here set your rest opacity between 0 to 1

});
});
</script>
```

reference **[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**